# Marketing Cloud API via Apex : persistant 401

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, api

I use my id & secret to obtain an access token but now matter what endpoint I try per the [Getting Started](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/using-the-api-key-to-authenticate-api-calls.html) I still get `System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]`

```
...
    String requestPath = 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/platform/v1/endpoints/';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(requestPath);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('Bearer', token);
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
...
```

I must be missing something pretty simple here...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I think at first i got your issue incorrectly.
I think your one header is wrong.It should be

```
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+token);
```

Please mark it if it helps you.

I'm keeping my old answer as well.

**Previous Answer:**

I am not much familiar with Marketing cloud but i tried in POSTMAN rest client to access request token.

> Endpoint URL: https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Body:
>
> {
>        "clientId": "pass your client id here",
>
> "clientSecret": "pass your client secret here"
>
> }
>
> Request Method: POST

And this way i got the access token.

You will get result like this:

> {
>       "accessToken": "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
>       "expiresIn": 3600 }

You can only use this token in further call for the specified time that is "expiresIn" time. After that you have to again make request for access token.