# How to pass accessToken to GET campaigns

Tags: api, campaign, python

I am trying to make a call the the campaigns GET request.

> https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns?$page=1&$pageSize=2&$orderBy=Name ASC

I use the following to get an accessToken.

```
  headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"clientId": "xx","clientSecret": "xx"}'

requests.post('https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken', headers=headers, data=data)
```

However I have no idea how to pass that to the GET request for campaigns.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: I get a 403","errorcode":0,"message":"Not Authorized"

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because at the time of making request **you are not correctly passing the access token.**

You have to pass the access token you got from request token request to GET request like this:

```
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+token);
```

see my answer here:

[Marketing Cloud API via Apex : persistant 401](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119877/marketing-cloud-api-via-apex-persistant-401/119892#119892)

Although i'm not very famillier with Python but looking at your code i can say that this will be like this:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
}
```

Comment: Is it a duplicate?

Comment: @mok is having trouble in writing python code with REST api's. So i won't say this as duplicate. mok is basically asking for help in python :)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have managed to achieve my aim of using the REST api to get campaign information.

Answer (score 1):

It would look something like the above, I am not sure the exact endpoint query, but this should give you a good starting point.

```
     Http h = new Http(); 
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
     HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse(); 
     req.setEndpoint('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns?$page=1&$pageSize=2&$orderBy=Name%ASC&access_token='+token); 
     req.setMethod('GET'); 
     req.setHeader('ContentSize','0'); 
     System.debug(req); 
     res=h.send(req);
```

Comment: The issue is the not passing the header or passing it incorrectly.See my answer.

Comment: Well I thought he already got the access token and he didn't know how to further make the request to the query presented above. Under this premises my solution is perfectly valid